# Blue screen. .dmp file?

Tags: windows, bsod

hi i am getting blue screens with the stop code : WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR I need help fixing it cuz I don't understand whats wrong

this are my specs

- rog strix x570-e gaming motherboard
- amd ryzen 9 5900x
- be quiet dark pro 4 cpu cooler
- 6x corsair ll120 rgb fans with the commander pro
- msi geforce rtx 2080 ti gaming x trio
- samsung 980 pro 1tb ssd
- samsung 860 500gb ssd
- 4x viper gaming 8gb ddr4 4400mhz (running on 3600mhz)
- lian li 011 dynamic xl case windows 10 pro

i have tried resetting it but it didn’t help

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.22473.1005 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\010222-14828-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (24 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`63000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`63c2a1b0
Debug session time: Sun Jan  2 19:48:10.620 2022 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:20:36.221
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.........................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.............
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff801`633f70d0 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:ffffa081`a5784940=0000000000000124
8: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
nt!_WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error condition. Try !errrec Address of the nt!_WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure to get more details.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffb607f3502028, Address of the nt!_WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000bc800800, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 00000000060c0859, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------

*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: hal!_WHEA_PROCESSOR_GENERIC_ERROR_SECTION                ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: hal!_WHEA_PROCESSOR_GENERIC_ERROR_SECTION                ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 2546

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 5236

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 155

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 2034

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 78

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


FILE_IN_CAB:  010222-14828-01.dmp

BUGCHECK_CODE:  124

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffb607f3502028

BUGCHECK_P3: bc800800

BUGCHECK_P4: 60c0859

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  Discord.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffa081`a5784938 fffff801`634b433a     : 00000000`00000124 00000000`00000000 ffffb607`f3502028 00000000`bc800800 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffa081`a5784940 fffff801`61f215b0     : 00000000`00000000 ffffb607`f3502028 ffffb607`efcf3d10 ffffb607`f3502028 : nt!HalBugCheckSystem+0xca
ffffa081`a5784980 fffff801`635b5fde     : 00000000`00000000 ffffa081`a5784a29 ffffb607`f3502028 ffffb607`efcf3d10 : PSHED!PshedBugCheckSystem+0x10
ffffa081`a57849b0 fffff801`634b5c61     : ffffb607`fa1dd900 ffffb607`fa1dd900 ffffb607`efcf3d60 ffffb607`efcf3d10 : nt!WheaReportHwError+0x46e
ffffa081`a5784a90 fffff801`634b5fd3     : 00000000`00000008 ffffb607`efcf3d60 ffffb607`efcf3d10 00000000`00000008 : nt!HalpMcaReportError+0xb1
ffffa081`a5784c00 fffff801`634b5eb0     : ffffb607`efafb5c0 00000000`00000000 ffffa081`a5784e00 00000000`00000000 : nt!HalpMceHandlerCore+0xef
ffffa081`a5784c50 fffff801`634b53f5     : ffffb607`efafb5c0 ffffa081`a5784ef0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!HalpMceHandler+0xe0
ffffa081`a5784c90 fffff801`634b7bb5     : ffffb607`efafb5c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!HalpHandleMachineCheck+0xe9
ffffa081`a5784cc0 fffff801`6350d2c9     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!HalHandleMcheck+0x35
ffffa081`a5784cf0 fffff801`634061fa     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiHandleMcheck+0x9
ffffa081`a5784d20 fffff801`63405eb7     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x7a
ffffa081`a5784e60 00000000`02e3338a     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x277
00000000`13acfdb8 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x2e3338a


MODULE_NAME: AuthenticAMD

IMAGE_NAME:  AuthenticAMD.sys

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_0_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR__UNKNOWN_IMAGE_AuthenticAMD.sys

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {035dcc87-485b-74b3-1c1b-ee50cb0c2865}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR means that a hardware error has occurred. Please post online the `.dmp` file for analysis.

Comment: how do i that ?

Comment: the dump file i copied it in my post

Comment: That's not it. Find the `.dmp` file in `C:\Windows\Minidump`, zip it up and upload online (OneDrive, Dropbox or other), then post here its link.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bfoertjv1j99esh/010222-14828-01.rar?dl=0 here it is

Comment: Please make sure to always use [proper formatting](https://superuser.com/editing-help) when writing questions or answers on the Stack Exchange network. Your question was _not readable_. Make sure to check the preview under the editor. Also, if you are able, please use proper English grammar and spelling. It goes a long way to make a question “accessible”.

Answer (score 0):

The analysis of your crash `.dmp` file shows that it's caused by a
hardware error, but does not indicate the faulting device.
The following is therefore a general troubleshooting advice:

- Search the Event Viewer for any message that can indicate the cause
  of the error
- In the event that the problem is still caused by software:

  - Update Windows to the latest version (for Windows 10, no need to go to
    Windows 11 yet)
  - Verify that your device drivers are updated
  - Run `chkdsk`
  - Run
    [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
    followed by
    [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Check the temperature sensors for overheating
- Run Windows Memory Diagnostic from *Start > Windows Memory Diagnostic*
  (this will take time)
- Do more extensive testing by running
  [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
  overnight; this will test the RAM and also the general functions.